# Date in SQL Select Query

Tags: sql

I have date in my select query in below format

```
Thu Sep 04 23:03:30 GMT 2014
```

and in my Table date is in this format

```
13-NOV-13 03.38.22.000000000 AM
```

How can I convert in the DB format. I tried using

```
TO_CHAR('Thu Sep 04 23:03:30 GMT 2014','DD-MMM-YY HH:MI:SS')
```

but not working. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to have that literal be a part of the select statement?

Comment: Then Shall I change the date in GMT format manually and use that in my query?

Comment: What are you trying to do? I guess I just don't understand the question.

Comment: I just wan't to convert the 1st format to 2nd format in Select query.

Comment: is this being used in the where clause with a comparison to the field you talk about in whatever table? If so, what data type is that field? My answer answers your question literally but I wonder if your actual issue is trying to compare a literal value with a timestamp field. If the field is a timestamp field, the format you posted is probably already converted from the actual value by whatever client side application you're using to access the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
select to_char(timestamp '2014-09-04 23:03:30 GMT','DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS')
from dual
```

converts the timestamp represented by 'Thu Sep 04 23:03:30 GMT 2014'

into the format 'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS' (I think you meant MON, not MMM)

But the input literal has to be changed to '2014-09-04 23:03:30 GMT' (as shown)

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/34741/0

**Output:**

```
04-SEP-14 11:03:30
```

The format you put in your select list only contains seconds, however, whereas you indicate you are storing fractional seconds in your table (likely a timestamp field), to match that format use FF rather than SS. Also, you indicate you are using HH12 format, not HH (12 hour vs. 24 hour). To do those you would want a different format than you are currently trying to convert to:

```
select to_char(timestamp '2014-09-04 23:03:30 GMT','DD-MON-YY HH12:MI:FF AM')
from dual
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/34744/0

Note that if the time were in the latter half of the day it would show PM rather than AM, despite the fact that you see AM in the sql (refer to http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php)

**Output:**

```
04-SEP-14 11:03:000000000 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
LEFT(DATENAME(dw,date),3) +' '+     CAST(date AS VARCHAR(20))
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could *edit your answer* and provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: @TarynEast Thanks for the information; I will be sure to explain my answers a bit more thoroughly next time.

Comment: You can do it this time too... just edit your answer and add a sentence or two :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to convert?

```
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),13)
```

All the diffrent date formats can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Based on the to_char function he is not using sql server.